# sed replace command inside of a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting, sed

I have a problem replacing a command inside of a script, the offending line in the script looks like this:

```
mail -s "$(hostname) on $(date)"
```

It should be replaced with a line like this:

```
nail -r "sender@domain.com" -s "Subject" -S smtp=255.255.255.255
```

But I can't get sed to do a replacement :) I wrote a small script for that purpose:

```
#!/bin/bash

old="mail -s \"\$(hostname) on \$(date)"
new="nail -r \"sender@domain.com\" -s \"Subject\" -S smtp=255.255.255.255"

sed -i 's|$old|$new|' script.sh
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -i "s|$old|$new|" script.sh
```

Note the double quotes.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this stupid mistake :) I've been using sed to replace and append double quotes where needed and got tired of escaping them all the time so i just started to put in single quotes and forgot about it :)

Answer (score 1):

Sed by default does not do in Place editing. If you are using gnu Sed try providing the in place flag -ikbak

Comment: The OP has the `-i` option in place. The only difference is that yours causes a backup to be created with the (unusual?) suffix "kbak".

Answer (score 0):

Better use ed!

http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php?id=howto:edit-ed